# NoMethodError: undefined method ID for Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I add `ID` method/attribute to a dialog hash? This is require because there might be more than one item and each needs an ID or key.

I get the error `NoMethodError: undefined method` id' for #Hash:0x000055b16edb60a8`.

```
  dialog_hash = {}

  response["value"].each_with_index do |mgmt_group, index|
    id = index     
    value = mgmt_group
    dialog_hash[mgmt_group.id] = "#{value}"
  end
```

Comment: `mgmt_group[:id]`?

Comment: I tried `mgmt_group[:id] = index` but still I can't use `dialog_hash[mgmt_group.id]`. Same error

Comment: there is no id method on a hash. `dialog_hash[mgmt_group[:id]] = value`

Comment: can you try `dialog_hash[index] = "#{value}"`??